# Have domain2 access subfolder of domain1 in nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I got a domain running WordPress and now I would like to add another domain that accesses a page of the first domain.

I want domain2.com to access my domain1.com/subfolder content without changing the URL in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Added the new domain to the nginx settings and installed the Domain Mapping System plugin.